# Error converting HttpClient response to JsonObject

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

I am working on an Android project and I am getting my Android app to post to a PHP REST web service, this web service then returns JSON for the Android app to process.

What the app does is allow the user to manage a MySQL Database from their android app so I am running a query on my database and am returning the JSON however I get a JSON exception. Below is the code I am using to post to the server and get the response back.

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try
                    {
                        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(serverUrl);
                        if (postData != null)
                        {
                            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postData));
                        }

                        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

                        String responseBody = httpClient.execute(httpPost, responseHandler);

                        Log.d(TAG + " Response", responseBody);

                        ServerResultProcessor serverResultProcessor = new ServerResultProcessor(progressDlg);
serverResultProcessor.processExecuteSqlQuery(iQueryExecution, 
                                new JSONObject(responseBody));
```

It throwing the exception on the `new JSONObject(responseBody)`. I know this works normally as I successfully process other JSON returned its just on this part of the app where it is not working.

Below is the code for how I am returning the JSON from PHP back to Android

```
function executeQuery($postData)
        {
            include_once ("ConnectionManager.php");
            $connManager = new ConnectionManager();
            $status = $connManager->connectToDBFromPostArray($postData);

            if ($status[RESULT] != SUCCESS)
            {
                print json_encode($status);
                exit();
            }

            $result = mysql_query(mysql_escape_string($postData['query']));

            if ($result)
            {
                $data = array();
                while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    $data[] = $myrow;
                }
                print json_encode($data);
            }
            else
            {
                $status = array();
                $status[RESULT] = ERROR;
                $status[MYSQL_ERROR] = mysql_error();
                $status[ERROR_NO] = mysql_errno();
                print json_encode($status);
            }
        }
```

Below is the JSON that is returned from the logcat

> 12-16 00:33:41.106: D/PostToApi Response(8513): [{"0":"1","id":"1","1":"1","SoftwareID":"1","2":"1","PlatformID":"1","3":"6.0.1.8","Version":"6.0.1.8"},{"0":"2","id":"2","1":"1","SoftwareID":"1","2":"1","PlatformID":"1","3":"6.0.1.9","Version":"6.0.1.9"},{"0":"3","id":"3","1":"1","SoftwareID":"1","2":"1","PlatformID":"1","3":"6.0.2.0","Version":"6.0.2.0"},{"0":"4","id":"4","1":"1","SoftwareID":"1","2":"1","PlatformID":"1","3":"6.0.2.1","Version":"6.0.2.1"},{"0":"5","id":"5","1":"1","SoftwareID":"1","2":"1","PlatformID":"1","3":"6.1.0.0","Version":"6.1.0.0"}]

Below is the exception:

> 12-16 00:33:41.110: E/PostToApi(8513): org.json.JSONException: Value [{"3":"6.0.1.8","id":"1","2":"1","1":"1","0":"1","PlatformID":"1","Version":"6.0.1.8","SoftwareID":"1"},{"3":"6.0.1.9","id":"2","2":"1","1":"1","0":"2","PlatformID":"1","Version":"6.0.1.9","SoftwareID":"1"},{"3":"6.0.2.0","id":"3","2":"1","1":"1","0":"3","PlatformID":"1","Version":"6.0.2.0","SoftwareID":"1"},{"3":"6.0.2.1","id":"4","2":"1","1":"1","0":"4","PlatformID":"1","Version":"6.0.2.1","SoftwareID":"1"},{"3":"6.1.0.0","id":"5","2":"1","1":"1","0":"5","PlatformID":"1","Version":"6.1.0.0","SoftwareID":"1"}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

I can't see anything wrong with this.

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: Sorry, would help if I included that, it doesn't seem to provide that much help though

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what the problem is ... the response is a JSON array, not a JSON object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your JSON

```
[{"0":"1","id":"1","1":"1","SoftwareID":"1","2":"1","PlatformID":"1","3":"6.0.1.8","Version":"6.0.1.8"},{"0":"2","id":"2","1":"1","SoftwareID":"1","2":"1","PlatformID":"1","3":"6.0.1.9","Version":"6.0.1.9"},{"0":"3","id":"3","1":"1","SoftwareID":"1","2":"1","PlatformID":"1","3":"6.0.2.0","Version":"6.0.2.0"},{"0":"4","id":"4","1":"1","SoftwareID":"1","2":"1","PlatformID":"1","3":"6.0.2.1","Version":"6.0.2.1"},{"0":"5","id":"5","1":"1","SoftwareID":"1","2":"1","PlatformID":"1","3":"6.1.0.0","Version":"6.1.0.0"}]
```

is an array (note the leading `[`) and you are trying to use it as a JSON object.

Use

```
new JSONArray(responseBody);
```

Comment: Thanks seems pretty obvious now

Comment: @Boardy You're welcome. Remember that the [JSON format doesn't have many types](http://www.json.org/). Familiarize yourself with them and you shouldn't have any further problems.